# Navigating out of a react-router single page application on the same host

Tags: reactjs, react-router, single-page-application

I'm trying to set up links that take the user out of the current SPA and into another one (or download a pdf).

I've tried using `<a>` tags, however whenever I navigate to the paths were I want to not be in the SPA anymore, it shows the basic layout of the SPA I'm stuck in.

If I hard refresh on the proper paths, I see the other SPA, and in another case the pdf I'm trying to view.

Example anchor element: `<a href="/requirements" rel="external" target="_blank">`

Router code:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App(Main)} />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I generated the both SPAs with create react app.  I also tried commenting out the service worker code, in case that was causing the issue.

I'm serving both SPAs using nginx reverse proxy.

I've also tried `window.location.reload(true)` to force a hard reload, but it still does not work.  I have to have chrome inspector open and cmd + shift + r to get a full hard reload.

Comment: Have you tried using window.location.replace('url') and making that url the full url (with the http and everything) to the other SPA?

Comment: I had not, however I don't know if it would be different than setting the location to a full URI

Answer (score 1):

Even though I stopped the service worker from loading, It was still registered (not sure if that it the right word) to the page.  I had to ensure the service working was not registered, then my navigation worked as expected.

Luckily, create-react-app has a nice function built in to unregister the service worker.

A next step would be to figure out how to keep the service worker, but specify urls to always pass through to the server.