# Is there a way to "Break out" of a react app with a relative link

Tags: reactjs, react-router

## Context

We have 2 distinct React JS applications both deployed behind a proxy.

The proxy serves one app (let's call it the home page) on the root `/` location. It serves the other on a subpath, e.g. `/application-a/`. Both are therefore on the same domain, e.g. `https://my-site.com/` and `https://my-site.com/application-a/`

This works great if I open 2 new browser windows and navigate 1 directly to `/` and the other directly to `/application-a/`.

The problem comes when I might want to use a HTML `a` tag inside the root path application (home page) and link this to the application running at `/application-a/` subpath using a relative `href`.

In this case I believe that the router kicks in and wants this to be route in the local app. I want to try to "escape" or "breakout" of the react router.

## Possible Solutions

1. I think if the anchor tag `href` in the root app has a `target` attribute value of `_blank` this works ok - but is undesirable as it forces a new tab to be loaded.
2. If I use an absolute URL for the `href` value then I think it will "escape" the SPA and access the new page in the same tab. Sounds great - but now I have to use absolute URL's making the code less portable between dev/staging/live etc.
3. Explicitly put a matching route in the router for `/application-a/` and programatically change the `window.location`? I could see this might work but feels messy to me.

## Question

Isn't there a way I can use good old fashioned anchor tags and maybe provided some type of attribute which tells the react router to "leave me alone" and let me behave like a "regular" anchor in a static HTML/non-SPA/non-React JS page.  If not, any other advice appreciated.

Similar unresolved question: [Navigating out of a react-router single page application on the same host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50081708/navigating-out-of-a-react-router-single-page-application-on-the-same-host?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a HashRouter instead? https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/HashRouter.md
URLs won't be "pretty", but it should work.

Alternatively, you could maybe redirect the user to the other app if the current urls doesn't match with any route definition, e.g.:

```
<Route render={() => (<Redirect to="http:/full-url-to/other-app" />)}/>
```

after all your other route definitions, so that it matches only when no other route matches.

About portability between different environments (staging, live, ...), consider you could also use Webpack DefinePlugin to set a variable at build time, so you can pass the base URL dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, we'd rather not use the hash router if possible. I'll look into the other option you mention. I presume it's not necessary to make it a match only when no other routes match and I could make it an exact match on the path I'm interested in (e.g. `/application-a/`).

Comment: @DavidGoate yeah, I think that's correct. Also, the render props on Route takes props as the first arg, so from there you can get the current path and append that to the absolute URL if you want to "deep-link" to the other app.

Comment: Marked as accepted, I won't use the hash router as business preference cares a bit about the presentation of the URLs. I'll try to use the second approach you detailed.